# Content Approval is stuck on

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-approval, check-in

A few weeks ago, I enabled Content Approval on a Wiki Library. Our team used it for a while, and decided that it was more of a burden than a help, so I disabled it in the Library Settings, just like how I enabled it.

However, whenever our users check pages in, their changes are not visible to anyone but those in the approvers group I created for content approval, and this appears at the top of the page:

[image]

What do I need to do to let anyone publish their changes, just by checking a document back in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are not publishing major version, publish a major version after check in. Major version should be like 3.0,4.0 etc...

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If I do that by changing the options in the Library Settings, what happens to all existing minor versions? Are they rounded up to a major version, and published, or are they rolled back to the last publish?

Comment: Ideally it should all change to major version, but please note that I have not tried this, so can't confirm. if you don't have many pages in wiki library you can do it manually also....  Just tell editor of page to publish major version after checking the file..

Comment: I just tried it, and it left minor versions with the same number (i.e. 8.2 instead of 9.0), but displayed them as major versions (without the yellow message). The version histories on the pages still show old draft (minor) versions, with their non-zero decimals. Thanks for your help!

Comment: np..glad it helped :)